# Manual for "processing " PyQGIS module

Tags: pyqgis, documentation

Does anyone know where I can find references for the modules and functions used in PyQgis?

Comment: I think you should definitely read this: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html#calling-algorithms-from-the-python-console

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the documentation and the cookbook:

- Documentation

  - https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/processing/index.html
  - https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html
- Cookbook

  - https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/processing.html